# How to defer custom action in scene startup?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'd like to access the root node of a scene, but even in its `_ready()` lifecycle method I get a runtime error telling the parent node is busy:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    self.get_tree().get_root().add_child(preload("res://MainMenu.tscn").instance())
    # This works:
    # self.get_tree().change_scene("res://MainMenu.tscn")
```

My current script is just changing scene for now. I know I can use this `[object NodeTree].change_scene()` method or `root_node.call_deferred()`, but I'd like to be able to observe to when the scene is fully initialized, so I can freely use its node tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time `_ready` runs, the parent node is not ready yet (let alone the scene root). Godot has not finished the routine that add children to the parent node. In fact, it just added your current node, the children of your current node, and is running `_ready` on your current node. After it has done that for your current node and its siblings, it will run `_ready` on your parent node, and so on, until it reaches the scene root… Then it will be ready.

Lightning_A is correct, inserting `yield(get_tree().get_root(), "ready")` before manipulating the root will work. `yield` will halt the execution and schedule it to continue after the given signal. The `ready` signal in this case. Which happens after `_ready` completed.

This is how you would use it:

```
func _ready():
    yield(get_tree().get_root(), "ready")
    get_tree().get_root().add_child(preload("res://MainMenu.tscn").instance())
```

Another common solution is to insert `yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")` instead. The signal `idle_frame` happens just before Godot calls `_process`:

```
func _ready():
    yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
    get_tree().get_root().add_child(preload("res://MainMenu.tscn").instance())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so this is a generator function!

Comment: @Klaider Kind of, not exactly, sort of. It is a [coroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine). GDScript does not have proper [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29) functions. GDScript `yield` is closer to `async/await` than to `yield return`. *That some other engines use generators (cought) Unity (cought) for asynchronous code, is another matter.* See [Coroutines with yield](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#coroutines-with-yield)

Comment: BTW `yield` has been replaced by `await` keyword, and now the signal is accessed with dot (e.g. `await get_tree().get_root().ready`). However `await get_tree().idle_frame` doesn't work.

Comment: @Klaider that would be for Godot 4.0 - Godot 3.3.2 still uses yield. Last time I tried using await in an unofficial build Godot 4.0 it crashed. I don't think I'll be writing answers for Godot 4.0 until it gets an official release.

Answer (score 1):

Does `Node`'s [`ready`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#signals) signal work for you? i.e. `yield(get_tree().get_root(), "ready")`